# RDLC export to PDF, different size from print layout

Tags: c#, pdf, rdlc

I have a `RDLC` report that I generate with dynamic size eveytime. My report in design has a standard height of 21 cm but the report height can change from 21cm to 24cm at runtime, I handle this with this code:

```
var size = new PaperSize("custom", widthInch, heightInch) { RawKind = 260 };
var pageSetting = new PageSettings
{
   Landscape = false,
   Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0),
   PaperSize = size
};
reportViewer1.SetPageSettings(pageSettings);
```

In `ReportView` the print layout is ok with the right size, the problem is that when I export it to PDF the size is fixed to the one I set in the designer, so 21cm.

What determine the size of the page when you export to pdf ? Is there a way to change it runtime ?

Thanks